# can't connect to kvm rhel guest from fedora host over any port other than 22 (ssh)

Tags: networking, linux-kvm, rhel-6, fedora-19

I have a kvm guest running Red Hat Linux in a Fedora 19 host. Running a ruby app in the guest on port 3000. I can ping the guest, and ssh into it from the host, but I cannot access the app itself. Trying via:

```
curl -v http://guest-ip:3000
```

This works fine on the guest locally (using the external IP address, not localhost)

I added an iptables rule to make sure the guest was allowing connections:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

However, when I try the above curl command (or telnet to the port), I get a 'No route to host' error.

Any ideas what I should look at?